# DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator causes MultibodyPlant to snap to the same uninitialized point at start up every time

Tags: drake

Drake version: Dockerhub latest (1.14.0)
Python 3.8, OS: Ubuntu 20.04

As mentioned in the title, using DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator (DIKI) with an Inverse Dynamics controller causes MultibodyPlant's end-effector to always snap momentarily to some off point before returning to the properly initialized pose at the beginning of a sim. We do check our `start_pose` with an ik solver to make sure it is achievable. We set positions for the diki using `diki.SetPositions(diki_context, start_pose)` and for the plant using `plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, joint_positions)`. So that should be all that's needed to set an iiwa robot's initial pose (or `start_pose`) right?

In this example we are using a slider to command the position of the end-effector (final iiwa_link: 7) that feeds the DIKI.
The graph below is visualizing the XYZ position of the end-effector (final iiwa_link: 7) every 0.1 delta_t. [As seen in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV8Zz.png) there are *three* red dots far left field showing where the DIKI snaps to at the beginning of any simulation. The other dots are the expected motion along the `x` and `y` axes which I commanded and are executed correctly.

Here is a jist of the code (won't run as is):

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001)
resource = FindResourceOrThrow(
        "drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_polytope_collision.sdf")
model = Parser(plant, scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(resource)

# Define frames for Cartesian motion planning
ref_frame = 'iiwa_link_0'
tip_frame = 'iiwa_link_7'
# Finalize the multi-body plant
plant.Finalize()

# Start the meshcat visualizer
meshcat = StartMeshcat()
MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)

# Create an arbitrary start pose for the robot
start_tcp_rt = RigidTransform(RollPitchYaw(np.array([np.pi, 0.0, 0.0])), np.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.3]))
start_pose = solve_ik(plant, model, ref_frame, tip_frame, [start_tcp_rt],
                        seed=np.ones(plant.num_actuated_dofs()) * 0.1, max_attempts=1)[0]
controller = InvDyn(plant, model)
DIKI(plant, model, start_pose, tip_frame=plant.GetFrameByName(tip_frame), euler_integr_time_step=0.1)
# Finalize the controller
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
diki.SetPositions(diki_context, start_pose)
plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, start_pose)

# Set up the simulation
simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
simulator.Initialize()

# Add a button to start the simulation
start_sim_button = 'Start Simulation'
meshcat.AddButton(start_sim_button)
# Wait until the start button is pressed before beginning the simulation
print(f'Press the \'{start_sim_button}\' to start the simulation')
while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(start_sim_button) < 1:
    time.sleep(1.0)

# Replace the start button with a stop button
meshcat.DeleteButton(start_sim_button)
stop_sim_button = 'Stop Simulation'
meshcat.AddButton(stop_sim_button)
while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(stop_sim_button) < 1:
    # Advance the simulation
    t = simulator.get_context().get_time()
    simulator.AdvanceTo(t + 0.1)

meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I cannot tell why the DIKI snaps to the same point at the beginning of every sim, no matter if I change the `start_pose`. It just whips and comes back.

Printing DIKI context before and after `simulator.Initialize()` shows the same:

```
Time: 0                                                                                                                                                               
States: 
  2 discrete state groups with 
     7 states  
         1.764131330322971   1.313860284302006  -1.458064433679016  -2.053485204838976  -1.750486209896251  -1.354796418277838 -0.2552547953113156
     1 states                                                                                                                                                         
       0
```

### Updated Edits to original post ---

Here is an isolated script of the code that causes this effect (for some reason now isolating it

`plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, start_pose)`

and

`diki.finalize(context, start_pose)`

no longer set the start_pose of the robot properly:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from pydrake.all import (AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, DiagramBuilder, FindResourceOrThrow, Parser, Simulator,
                         SceneGraph, GeometryFrame, MeshcatVisualizer, RigidTransform, RollPitchYaw, Solve, RotationMatrix, InverseKinematics, DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator,
                         DifferentialInverseKinematicsParameters, DiscreteDerivative, FramePoseVector, InverseDynamicsController, ConstantVectorSource, ConstantValueSource, Value, AbstractValue, Multiplexer, PassThrough, BasicVector, LeafSystem)
from pydrake.geometry import MeshcatVisualizer

# Utilties
from src.mast.visualization import StartMeshcat, Meshcat, MeshcatPoseSliders, AddTriad

class AnimatedFrame(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, scene_graph: SceneGraph, name: str, triad_length: float = 0.2,
                 triad_radius: float = 0.005, triad_opacity: float = 0.5):
        """ Parent class for animated frames that aren't bodies
        :param scene_graph: Scene Graph
        :param name: desired frame name
        """
        super().__init__()
        # Create geometry/frame
        self.sid = scene_graph.RegisterSource()
        frame = GeometryFrame(name)
        # Register geometry with scene graph
        self.m_frame_id = scene_graph.RegisterFrame(self.sid, frame)
        # Add a visualization for the set point
        AddTriad(self.sid, self.m_frame_id, scene_graph, length=triad_length,
                 radius=triad_radius, opacity=triad_opacity, name=frame.name())

class SetPointVisualizer(AnimatedFrame):
    def __init__(self, scene_graph: SceneGraph, name: str):
        super().__init__(scene_graph, name)
        self.input_port = self.DeclareAbstractInputPort('u', Value[RigidTransform]())
        self.output_port = self.DeclareAbstractOutputPort(name='y', alloc=Value[FramePoseVector], calc=self.calc)

    def calc(self, context, output):
        fpv = FramePoseVector()
        fpv.set_value(id=self.m_frame_id, value=self.input_port.Eval(context))
        output.SetFrom(AbstractValue.Make(fpv))

class StateExtractor(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, n_dof: int, n_p: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_dof = n_dof
        self.n_p = n_p
        if self.n_p > self.n_dof:
            input_size = 13 + 2 * n_dof
        else:
            input_size = 2 * n_dof

        self.input_port = self.DeclareVectorInputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE", BasicVector(input_size))
        self.output_port = self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE", BasicVector(2 * n_dof), self.calc_output)

    def calc_output(self, context, output):
        total_state = self.input_port.Eval(context)
        if self.n_p > self.n_dof:
            pose = total_state[7:(self.n_dof+7)]
            vel = total_state[(13+self.n_dof):]
            output.SetFromVector(np.hstack([pose, vel]))
        else:
            output.SetFromVector(np.hstack([total_state[:self.n_dof*2]]))

class CartesianSliderTrajectorySource():
    """
    Controls a robot by using Meshcat sliders to define set points for the end effector
    """
    def __init__(self, meshcat: Meshcat,
                 initial_pose: RigidTransform,
                 rotation_limits = (-np.pi, np.pi),
                 translation_limits = (-3, 3)):
        builder = DiagramBuilder()

        # Generate Pose Sliders & Add them to the system
        min_limits = (rotation_limits[0],) * 3 + (translation_limits[0],) * 3
        max_limits = (rotation_limits[1],) * 3 + (translation_limits[1],) * 3
        values = MeshcatPoseSliders.Value(*np.hstack([initial_pose.rotation().ToRollPitchYaw().vector(), initial_pose.translation()]))
        mps = MeshcatPoseSliders(meshcat, min_range=min_limits, max_range=max_limits, value=values)
        sliders = builder.AddNamedSystem("sliders", mps)

        # Export the pose from the slider as an output port
        builder.ExportOutput(sliders.get_output_port(), "DESIRED_EE_POSE")

        # Create a constant vector system that outputs zeros as the desired Cartesian velocity
        cvs = builder.AddNamedSystem("const_vector_zeros", ConstantVectorSource(np.zeros((6,))))
        # Export the zero velocity vector as the desired velocity output port
        builder.ExportOutput(cvs.get_output_port(), "DESIRED_EE_VELOCITY")

        # Generate the finalized diagram
        self.diagram = builder.Build()

    def get_diagram(self):
        return self.diagram

class InvDyn():
    def __init__(self,
                 plant,
                 model,
                 kp: float = 100.0,
                 ki: float = 1.0,
                 kd: float = 2.0 * np.sqrt(100.0 / 2.0),
                 ref_accel: bool = False):
        builder = DiagramBuilder()
        self.ref_accel = ref_accel
        self.n_dof = plant.num_actuated_dofs(model)

        kp_v = np.full((self.n_dof,), kp)
        ki_v = np.full((self.n_dof,), ki)
        kd_v = np.full((self.n_dof,), kd)

        # overloaded function, in welded states you can just input the plant instead of P_x,P_y
        jsc = builder.AddNamedSystem('Inverse Dynamics Controller', InverseDynamicsController(
            plant, kp_v, ki_v, kd_v, self.ref_accel))

        # self.input_port_desired_state = builder.AddSystem(PassThrough(2*n_dof))
        builder.ExportInput(
            jsc.get_input_port_desired_state(), "DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE")

        # self.input_port_estimated_state = builder.AddSystem(PassThrough(2*n_dof))
        builder.ExportInput(
            jsc.get_input_port_estimated_state(), "CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE")

        # output_actuation_command = builder.AddSystem(PassThrough(2 * n_dof))
        builder.ExportOutput(
            jsc.get_output_port(), "ACTUATION_COMMAND")
        self.diagram = builder.Build()

    def get_diagram(self):
        return self.diagram

class DIKI():
    def __init__(self,
                 plant,
                 model,
                 euler_integr_time_step: float = None,
                 tip_frame = None):
        n_dof = plant.num_actuated_dofs(model)
        self.builder = DiagramBuilder()

        # Create a DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator
        self.parameters = DifferentialInverseKinematicsParameters(n_dof, n_dof)

        # Set the position, velocity, and acceleration limits
        self.parameters.set_joint_acceleration_limits(
            (plant.GetAccelerationLowerLimits()[-n_dof:], plant.GetAccelerationUpperLimits()[-n_dof:]))
        self.parameters.set_joint_velocity_limits(
            (plant.GetVelocityLowerLimits()[-n_dof:], plant.GetVelocityUpperLimits()[-n_dof:]))
        self.parameters.set_joint_position_limits(
            (plant.GetPositionLowerLimits()[-n_dof:], plant.GetPositionUpperLimits()[-n_dof:]))

        self.use_robot_state = False
        # Make all the required leaf systems
        self.diki = self.builder.AddNamedSystem('DIKI Controller', DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator(
            plant, tip_frame, euler_integr_time_step, self.parameters))
        self.builder.ExportInput(self.diki.GetInputPort('X_WE_desired'), "X_WE_DESIRED")
        self.builder.ExportInput(self.diki.GetInputPort('robot_state'), "ROBOT_STATE")

        self.diki_derivative = self.builder.AddNamedSystem('discrete_derivative', DiscreteDerivative(n_dof, euler_integr_time_step))

        self.desired_system_state = self.builder.AddNamedSystem('multiplexer', Multiplexer([n_dof, n_dof]))
        self.builder.ExportOutput(self.desired_system_state.get_output_port(), "DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE")

        const_bool = self.builder.AddNamedSystem("boolean_source", ConstantValueSource(AbstractValue.Make(self.use_robot_state)))
        # Turn on the DIKI's use_robot_state boolean port
        self.builder.Connect(const_bool.get_output_port(0), self.diki.GetInputPort('use_robot_state'))

        # Connect the DIKI Output to the Torque Controller's Input for Desired State
        self.builder.Connect(self.diki.GetOutputPort('joint_positions'), self.diki_derivative.get_input_port())
        self.builder.Connect(self.diki_derivative.get_output_port(), self.desired_system_state.get_input_port(1))
        self.builder.Connect(self.diki.GetOutputPort('joint_positions'), self.desired_system_state.get_input_port(0))

        #desired_ee_velocity = self.builder.AddNamedSystem("desired_ee_vel_passthrough", PassThrough([0] * 6))
        #self.builder.ExportInput(desired_ee_velocity.get_input_port(), trajectory_system.GetOutputPort("DESIRED_EE_VELOCITY"))

        self.diagram = self.builder.Build()

    def get_diagram(self):
        return self.diagram

    def finalize(self, context, start_pose):
        diki_context = self.diki.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context)
        self.diki.SetPositions(diki_context, start_pose)

def main():
    ####### INITIALIZE THE PLANT ###############################################################
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001)
    resource = FindResourceOrThrow(
            "drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_polytope_collision.sdf")
    model = Parser(plant, scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(resource)

    # Define frames for Cartesian motion planning
    ref_frame_name = 'iiwa_link_0'
    tip_frame_name = 'iiwa_link_7'
    # Disable gravity
    plant.gravity_field().set_gravity_vector([0., 0., 0.])

    plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.get_body(
    plant.GetBodyIndices(model)[0]).body_frame())

    # Finalize the multi-body plant
    plant.Finalize()
    plant_context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
    n_dof = plant.num_actuated_dofs(model)

    # Start the meshcat visualizer
    meshcat = StartMeshcat()
    MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)

    ####### GENERATE A START POSE ##############################################################
    seed = np.ones(plant.num_actuated_dofs()) * 0.1
    # Extract the frame objects
    ref_frame = plant.GetFrameByName(ref_frame_name)
    tip_frame = plant.GetFrameByName(tip_frame_name)

    # Populate the upper and lower position bounds
    pos_error_tol = 1.0e-6
    rot_error_tol = np.radians(1.0e-3)
    ub = np.full(3, pos_error_tol)
    lb = np.full(3, -pos_error_tol)

    # Create an arbitrary start pose for the robot
    start_tcp_rt = RigidTransform(RollPitchYaw(np.array([np.pi, 0.0, 0.0])), np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]))
    poses = [start_tcp_rt]
    ik_poses = np.full((len(poses), n_dof), np.nan)
    for idx, pose in enumerate(poses):
        ik = InverseKinematics(plant, plant_context)
        ik.AddPositionConstraint(
            ref_frame, pose.translation(), tip_frame, p_AQ_upper=ub, p_AQ_lower=lb)
        ik.AddOrientationConstraint(ref_frame, pose.rotation(), tip_frame, RotationMatrix.Identity(), theta_bound=rot_error_tol)
        result = Solve(ik.prog(), initial_guess=seed)
        attempts = 1
        while not result.is_success() and attempts < 5:
            seed[-n_dof:] = np.random.random(n_dof)
            result = Solve(ik.prog(), initial_guess=seed)
            attempts += 1

        if result.is_success():
            ik_poses[idx, :] = result.GetSolution(ik.q())[-n_dof:]
            start_pose = ik_poses[0]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Could not find a valid IK solution for the start pose! Please try another start pose.")
    ####### CREATE SUBSYSTEMS ##############################################################
    state_extractor = builder.AddNamedSystem("state_extractor", StateExtractor(
            plant.num_actuated_dofs(model), plant.num_positions(model)))

    traj_source = CartesianSliderTrajectorySource(meshcat, initial_pose=start_tcp_rt)
    trajectory_system = builder.AddNamedSystem("TrajectorySystem", traj_source.get_diagram())

    joint_space_controller = InvDyn(plant, model)
    jsc_system = builder.AddNamedSystem("JointSpaceController", joint_space_controller.get_diagram())

    euler_integr_time_step = 0.1
    diki = DIKI(plant, model, euler_integr_time_step, tip_frame)
    diki_system = builder.AddNamedSystem("DIKI", diki.get_diagram())

    ###### CONNECTs ########################################################################
    builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(model), state_extractor.GetInputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE"))
    builder.Connect(state_extractor.GetOutputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE"), diki_system.GetInputPort('ROBOT_STATE'))
    builder.Connect(trajectory_system.GetOutputPort("DESIRED_EE_POSE"), diki_system.GetInputPort('X_WE_DESIRED'))
    builder.Connect(diki_system.GetOutputPort("DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE"), jsc_system.GetInputPort("DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE"))
    builder.Connect(state_extractor.GetOutputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE"), jsc_system.GetInputPort("CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE"))
    builder.Connect(jsc_system.GetOutputPort("ACTUATION_COMMAND"), plant.get_actuation_input_port(model))

    # Visualize the Cartesian set point
    set_point = builder.AddNamedSystem("set_point_visualizer",
                                    SetPointVisualizer(scene_graph=scene_graph, name="set_point"))
    builder.Connect(set_point.get_output_port(), scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(set_point.sid))
    builder.Connect(trajectory_system.GetOutputPort("DESIRED_EE_POSE"), set_point.get_input_port())

    # Finalize
    # Construct the diagram
    diagram = builder.Build()
    context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, start_pose)
    diki.finalize(context, start_pose)

    ###### SIM SETUP ############################################################################
    # Set up the simulation
    simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
    simulator.Initialize()

    # Add a button to start the simulation
    start_sim_button = 'Start Simulation'
    meshcat.AddButton(start_sim_button)
    # Wait until the start button is pressed before beginning the simulation
    print(f'Press the \'{start_sim_button}\' to start the simulation')
    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(start_sim_button) < 1:
        time.sleep(1.0)

    # Replace the start button with a stop button
    meshcat.DeleteButton(start_sim_button)
    stop_sim_button = 'Stop Simulation'
    meshcat.AddButton(stop_sim_button)

    # Run the simulation
    while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(stop_sim_button) < 1:
        # Advance the simulation
        t = simulator.get_context().get_time()
        simulator.AdvanceTo(t + 0.1)

    meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is the optional `robot_state` input port also connected?  If this is connected, then the internal integrator will be set to this port in an initialization event (over-riding your call to `SetPositions`).

I'd recommend printing the DIKI context, then calling `simulator.Initialize()`, then printing the context again to debug?

Comment: FWIW -- I found the existing docstring for that system to be confusing, so I've opened https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19173 to hopefully improve it.

Comment: @RussTedrake Thanks for updating the docstring it definitely is clearer now. However my issue persists the DIKI context is unchanged before & after `simulator.Initialize()`
```
Time: 0 
States:
  2 discrete state groups with
   7 states         
      1.764131330322971   1.313860284302006  -1.458064433679016  -2.053485204838976  -1.750486209896251  -1.354796418277838 -0.2552547953113156 
 1 states 
  0
```
Tried both w optional `robot_state` input port connected and w/o. It performs the whip motion slower connected `use_robot_state` was set `True` when `robot_state` port is connected

Comment: It seems your example above is close to a reproduction.  If you can provide a runnable reproduction, i can take a look.

Comment: Not nearly near reproduction, but I cut out the classes we're using for this and isolated everything into one script. Placing it in the original post above. For some reason now with it isolated,
```
plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, start_pose)
diki.finalize(context, start_pose)
```
don't set the starting pose of the robot in sim anymore. While in our (much more intertwined and involved) code these two lines suffice to set the start_pose. However, like I mentioned is the issue with our code, the robot snaps to a far set point at the beginning of every simulation.

Comment: @RussTedrake I've also realized by printing the diki context as you recommended earlier, that in this isolated code (posted above in the original post now), simulator.Initialize() resets the diki's state (and I suspect the plant's too). If you attempt calling ``` plant.SetPositions(plant_context, model, start_pose) diki.finalize(context, start_pose) ``` after simulator.Initialize() instead of before it. It will set it only on clicking the start sim button. Really weird action.

Comment: The final error was just because you were setting the wrong context.  You need to call `plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(context)` before the call to `plant.SetPositions(plant_context, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your example. The `DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator` is working the way that you expect. But you're generating the initial kick because of the way that you are using the `DiscreteDerivative`, without initializing its state. (The `DiscreteDerivative` is estimating a huge derivative in the first step.)

Passing the additional `suppress_initial_transient=True` argument when you construct the `DiscreteDerivative` resolves the problem:

```
        self.diki_derivative = self.builder.AddNamedSystem('discrete_derivative', DiscreteDerivative(n_dof, euler_integr_time_step, suppress_initial_transient=True))
```

Comment: fwiw -- i've gone ahead and made `suppress_initial_transient=True` be the default.  https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19247

Comment: That was it. Thanks Russ. I see you've also updated its default configuration. Why is it estimating a huge derivative in the first step anyways? Why is it not initialized to a zero state by default? I agree it does make sense to have DiscreteDerivative's suppress_initial_transient default to True and only if the user wants to account for this behavior in the first time step in a simulation should they set it to False. It set us back a bit... but we appreciate your promptness and help!